# how to set fix image height in list view 100%

Tags: android, arrays

Here I have used code as,space is occurred how i can remove  this space[image]

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" /
```

>

Comment: `android:layout_height="match_parent"` not working for you?

Comment: post full xml code of row_layout

Comment: post whole adapter layout xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `android:layout_height="match_parent"` instead of 110dp.

> Never hardcode values like that, always use layouts, weights, proportions etc. because **EVEN** if it looks good on your device, it might look wrong on a different device with a different screen size/pixel density.

Answer (score 1):

use this in ImageView

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that extra space because of your Text View (ex:"Google is a Multinational Publicly Traded Organization") varies in number of lines, some text have 3 lines and some text 2 lines, Ur image height works perfectly for 2 lines text but for 3 lines text it will get a space. So My suggestion is you can restrict your item text view for maxlines is equal to two and it will fix ur problem.

**Insert This In Your ListView Item TextView**

```
android:maxLines="2"
```